# wordpress how to find the link files in server

Tags: php, wordpress, lamp

I am using linux and have lamp installed.

I am using wordpress and copied a site  (eg: himalaya.com) locally from server. I made a virtual host called himalaya.com

I am able to open the himalaya.com but when i open any link like `himalaya.com/ganga` it says `Object not found!. Error 404.`

I dont know which file is this `himalaya.com/ganga` is looking for in the `documentroot` folder. IN php how to know which file links to which link in the webpage.

Can anyone help me

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled on the new server (assuming you're using apache)?

Comment: Check your root `.htaccess` file

Comment: i have the .htaccess file. I dont know how to check it. What should i check it for. I have mod_rewrite enabled in apache

Comment: look into the error log file

Comment: there is nothing much in the error log

Comment: sorry i found this `client denied by server configuration:`

Comment: Are the permalinks set to /%category%/%postname%/ or do you actually have a folder named "ganga" on the server?

Comment: I dont know how the link is set, where can i find. IN the html code of the himalaya.com it shows the href as himalaya.com/ganga. IN my folder himalaya.com i dont see any folder named ganga

Comment: i found it, i have added allowoveride all in the direcroty then it worked